# Using Python nodes in Node-RED without exposing code

Tags: python, node-red

I want to set up a Node-RED GUI with multiple inputs and outputs etc. and some nodes containing python functions. The partner who will use this wants to input some own custom processors to work with the data and should be able to access my python functions, but I don't want to expose all the code I used. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The best you could do is to create a fork of the Python Function node that loads the python from a file rather than present a edit area in the Node-RED editor.

The python code would still be available on the disk of the machine running Node-RED but wouldn't be accessible via  the editor. This works if the partner is only accessing Node-RED via the web, but if they have access to the machine it's running on then they will have access to everything.